# Mysql Syntax "if length then" statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, syntax

I have a problem with syntax from mysql.
i have my subselect:

```
(SELECT uniqueid AS uniqueid_idx, calldate, src, dst, dstchannel, billsec, 
 SUBSTR(CONVERT(IF(LENGTH(dst)>8,cdr.dst,CONCAT('67',cdr.dst)),UNSIGNED INTEGER),1,6) prefixo_normal 
FROM cdr)
```

Can you see: "if you have cdr.dst > 8 then concat.."
now i want verify: "if cdr.dst have  <5 then create virtual column name RAMAL"

I have tried this syntax: `IF(LENGTH(cdr.dst)  <4, THEN cdr.dst AS ramal END`

but not working.

How can i do it?

Thank you !

Comment: You only put parentheses around subqueries.  Is this a subquery?  Also, you should identify what the error is, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: You can't create a column conditionally. The column is always there, you can only use a conditional to determine what to put in it.

Comment: Use `IF(LENGTH(dst) < 4, dst, NULL) AS ramal`

Comment: You seem to be mixing up the syntax for `IF` and `CASE`. Which is surprising, because you got the syntax correct in your original `IF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
SELECT uniqueid AS uniqueid_idx, calldate, src, dst, dstchannel, billsec, 
        SUBSTR(CONVERT(IF(LENGTH(dst)>8,cdr.dst,CONCAT('67',cdr.dst)),UNSIGNED INTEGER),1,6) prefixo_normal,
        IF(LENGTH(dst) < 4, dst, NULL) AS ramal
FROM cdr
```

There's no `THEN` or `END` when you use the `IF` function.